# How to send SMS (WhatsApp) to any number?

Tags: python-3.x, twilio, twilio-api

How can I send an SMS to any number? Currently, I only send SMS to 1 number, the amount is also being cut. I try to send to another number but I get: "Error 63016 "Failed to send freeform message because you are outside the allowed window. Please use a Template.""

I have valid account.

CURRENT BALANCE: +$13.7581.

I have Active Numbers: +31 97010205...

WhatsApp Senders-->
WhatsApp number:  +31 97010205...
Sender status: Online.

Whatsapp Business Account ID:  10400418609..
Meta Business Manager ID:  2663647191...

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = 'ACe97bbc91bb29a0........'
auth_token = '1b4aaba40725f9595.....'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
                              from_='whatsapp:+31970....',
                              body='Test',
                              to='whatsapp:+99559....'
                          )

print(message.sid)
```

send sms in whatsapp

Comment: Do you have an approved template with the text `Test`? Probably not. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/63016 has more details.

Comment: Yes, I chave and it has Status: Waiting for WhatsApp Approval.  Can you recommend a simple template with the text?

Comment: Well, "Waiting for WhatsApp Approval" and "Approved" aren't the same, are they?

Comment: yes, OK, Thanks for the help. I went through several validations and thought it was no longer necessary.

Comment: @JoachimSauer can you help me? status: translations approved by WhatsApp.  But I can not send sms :(.

Comment: SMS and WhatsApp are two different things. Are you having issues with sending SMS or Whatsapp? SMS should always go through in the same country, sending to another country might fail because of the [Geo permissions](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181108-International-SMS-Messaging-Geographic-Permissions-Geo-Permissions-and-How-They-Work).

Comment: If the WhatsApp doesn't go through, please consult the log. Maybe your sent messages doesn't match the approved template exactly